Jitsi Iframe Jwt Auth
I have a self-hosted Jitsi server with JWT token authentication. When a client accesses the iframe and creates a room, it sends a JWT token to allow access to the room. However, the issue is that all clients or participants joining the room are becoming moderators because they are sending this JWT token. What configuration should I change to fix this?
This is the JWT payload I'm using for Jitsi: [ "context" => [ "user" => [ "id" => "1", "name" => "John Doe", // "moderator" => false, // "role" => "participants", // "role" => "participant", ], ], // "moderator" => false, "aud" => "my_jitsi_app_id", "iss" => "my_jitsi_app_id", "sub" => "xxx.host.com", "room" => "room1", "exp" => "3600" ]
I have tried several methods such as setting the moderator to false, using the role as participant, but there has been no change.
I expected only the user who creates the room to have moderator permissions, while other participants joining the room would be regular participants without moderator rights
